# How to edit dynamically created HTML table using StringBuilder

Tags: c#, jquery, vb.net, stringbuilder

I created a dynamic HTML table using StringBuilder. But when I am trying to pass it's cell value to jQuery Ajax call, I am not getting the correct values. How will I get the cell values after focus out?

Here's the exact code snippet:

```
Dim table as new StringBuilder()
For each item in strategy

table.AppendLine(String.Format(“<td>{0}</td>”,item.id);

table.AppendLine(“<td>{0}</td>”,item.price);

table.AppendLine(“<td contenteditable=“”true”” onfocusout =“SaveVal({0},{1})””>{1}</td>”,item.id, item.cellvalue );

Next

Return table.tostring ();
```

SaveVal Jquery method in .aspx file:

```
function SaveVal(id,cellvalue){
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"Maintenance.aspx/SaveVal",
contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
dataType:"json",
data: JSON.stringify({
ids: id,
val:cellvalue
}),
async:false,
success:function(response){
alert("Value Saved");
}
});
}
```

I want to get this content editable cell value after focus out. `SaveVal(id,cellvalue)` function is defined in jQuery Ajax call and I want to pass these 2 parameters `id` and `cellvalue` which is the final value of the cell- if there is no edit then-existing value and if we edit and type new value then the new value will be passed.

Comment: When including code in your question, always format as code. This appears to be C# not vb.net. Please correct your tags.

Comment: A `StringBuilder` doesn't have an `html` property or field so how can that possibly work? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which would include examples of what you expect and what you get.

Comment: Also, you have tagged this question `jquery` but there's nothing relevant to that tag in the question. Either include the relevant information or remove the tag.

Comment: I would argue this is more a javascript issue. Nothing appears to be needed server-side. Please show the `SaveVal` method.

Comment: Code edited with exact syntax and snippet. Please help!

Comment: vb.net as well as jquery method also attached. Please let me know if anyone need more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up get rid of the inline javascript, it is no longer best practice.

Next, give your table an id or another way of identifying it (for my example I'm going to use an id of "MyTable".

Then, as you've indicated jquery is in use, we will assign a jquery event handler.

**vb.net**

```
Dim table as new StringBuilder()
For each item in strategy

'give this an identifiyer to explicitly find it in jQuery/javascript
table.AppendLine(String.Format("<td data-id>{0}</td>",item.id);

table.AppendLine("<td>{0}</td>",item.price);

'no more inline javascript 
table.AppendLine("<td contenteditable=""true"">{1}</td>",item.id, item.cellvalue );

Next

Return table.tostring ();
```

**jquery/javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*Event handler for foucusout content edtitable cells in MyTable*/
    $("#MyTable [contenteditable=true]").on("focusout", function(){ 
       //Get ID
       let id = $(this).prevAll("[data-id]:first").text();
       //Get value of this cell
       let cellvalue = $(this).text();
       //Call your function, or just put its contents here
       SaveVal(id,cellvalue);
    });
});

function SaveVal(id,cellvalue){
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"Maintenance.aspx/SaveVal",
    contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      ids: id,
      val:cellvalue
  }),
    async:false,
    success:function(response){
      alert("Value Saved");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. I am getting cellvalue to the jquery, but data-id is giving issues as its giving "undefined" value. Also .prevAll("[data-id]")[0].text() is not working. It says .text() is not defined and cannot be used with .prevAll.

Comment: Yup, been a while since I've worked with jquery. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you Jon. It’s working as expected now. Appreciate your help!